# Domain and Range of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

> Define a surface by the rule:
>   $$q(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> -\log_{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2}}+2\right), & (x,y)\in D)\\ 
>  1,& (x,y)=(0,0)
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>
> I need to find the maximal domain $D$, and range $R$ corresponding to the domain $D\cup \{(0,0)\}$.

---

I have gotten $x^2+y^2>2$, but how do I notate this with set notation for  $D$.

For the range, $R$, I have calculated $R\in (-\infty,-\log_{2}2)\cup 1$.

Are these correct? If not, any hints?

Comment: $D = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2>2\}$. The range is correct. But can you express $\log_22$ in a different way?

Comment: @amsmath, ah of course! Thank you

Comment: So, what is $\log_22$?

Comment: 1! thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, it's one..